# XSD: Is the parent element optional when the child sequence has minOccurs=0?

Tags: xml, xsd

Given the XSD file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="myElement" type="myType"/>
 <xs:complexType name="myType">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="myContent">
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="myContentElement" nillable="true" type="myContentType"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

Does the minOccurs in the innermost sequence propagate up in some way?

In other words: would the following be valid xml for this XSD:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><myElement/>`?

I would have expected to get at least this:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><myElement><myContent/></myElement>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the requiredness of an element is unaffected by the requiredness of the children elements in its content model.  Your first example would be invalid; your second example would be valid.

Of course, if a parent element is optional and omitted, then its children elements cannot be present.  It's only if the parent element is present that the requiredness of its children matter.